# How to compile solidity release version

Tags: solidity, solc, build-from-source

I've followed [instruction](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/installing-solidity.html) to build solidity. But when it finished, i've got develop version:

```
Version: 0.4.16-develop.2017.8.31+commit.d7661dd9.mod.Linux.g++
```

I've tried to run make with argument CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release - the same result.
Code was checked out from tagged version v0.4.16.
Without release version I cannot compile sol files with version 0.4.16 because of error:

```
Error: Source file requires different compiler version (current compiler is 0.4.16-develop.2017.8.31+commit.d7661dd9.mod.Linux.g++ - note that nightly builds are considered to be strictly less than the released version
```

Answer (score 2):

I've find out it by myself - to make release build just need create empty file prerelease.txt in source directory.